# Swift protocol class/AnyObject restriction in extension

Tags: swift, protocols

I have 2 protocols, one that gives an object a `serverId` and the other one that gives him a `status` (aka is it published on the server or not).
The two of them allow me to handle synchronization between my server model and Core Data.

```
/// By conforming to this protocol, classes AND struct have an identifiable serverid `Int64`
protocol RemoteObject {
    var serverId: ServerId { get set }
}

/// This can only be applied to class
protocol Syncable: class {
    var syncStatus: SyncStatus { get set }

}

enum SyncStatus: Int64 {
    case published
    case local
}
```

The idea behind it is that `RemoteObject` can be applied to struct (i.e. The **JSON structures** I get back from server) and class (`NSManagedObject`). On the other hand, `Syncable` can only be applied to class (`NSManagedObject`).

Next step for me is, when the `syncStatus` is set to `.local` I also need to get rid of the `serverId` from RemoteObject on my object by setting it to -1, but when I try I get this error:

```
extension Syncable where Self: RemoteObject {
    var syncStatus: SyncStatus {
        get {
            SyncStatus(rawValue: syncStatusValue) ?? .local
        }
        set {
            syncStatusValue = newValue.rawValue
            if newValue == .local { serverId = -1 } //  Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
        }
    }
}
```

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

I understand that I get this error because `RemoteObject` can be applied to structs, which are immutable.

**However**, considering that `Syncable` can only be applied to class types, doesnt it force `RemoteObject` to be applied on a class? and then be mutable?

Is there a way to force `RemoteObject` to be **class type** in my extension? for instance `extension Syncable where Self: RemoteObject & class` ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution eventually. According to this [post](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-can-we-not-mutate-mutable-members-on-a-reference-type/21619) I can do this :

```
extension Syncable where Self: RemoteObject {
    var syncStatus: SyncStatus {
        get {
            SyncStatus(rawValue: syncStatusValue) ?? .local
        }
        set {
            syncStatusValue = newValue.rawValue
            if newValue == .local { 
                var s = self
                s.serverId = -1
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This gets rid of the error, and, as far as I understand, this will change `serverId` for classes which are reference types, and not mutate the structs which are value types ( *Anyway they cannot conform to this protocol* ).

---

To go further, for who may find this post useful. My understanding of the issue was not accurate. At first I thought that the issue was on the `RemoteObject` protocol, which could be applied to any type.

The problem seems to be the other way, according to this [discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/protocol-extension-with-type-restriction-anyobject-class/39632/4). When restricting a procotol co `:class` or `:AnyObject`, it makes forces its `setter` to be **immutable**.

Then, when I am trying to change the value of `serverId`, I am calling a **mutable** setter from an **immutable** one which causes the compiler to complain. The work-around is fine for my usage, however to get a proper solution, I should get rid of the `:class` in `Syncable`, and deal with all the reasons that forced me to make it class-only in the first place.

Comment: This is interesting. Run it on a Playground and I was expecting `var s = self` to make a copy of `self`, but of course this is not the case because `Syncable` is always a class. So, this is just for silencing the compiler.

Comment: @gcharita I tried it in an `XCTest` and it works just fine. This is still bugging me though, the error shouldnt show on the first version of my setter, because it can only be a reference type. The error should only show when I get rid of `class` or `AnyObject` for `Syncable`